# Given a CDF how do I know that the PDF exists?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let us consider the following distribution function for the R.V. X. Does X have a density function $f(x)$??

$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{for $x<-2$ } \\
1/8(x+2)^2, & \text{for $-2\le x<0$ } \\
1/4(x+2),& \text{for $0\le x<2$} \\
1,& \text{for $x\geq 2$} \\
\end{cases}
$$

I know that we can talk about pdf iff $F(X)$ is absolutely continuous.
I know that a distribution function is absolutely continuous iff there exists a nonnegative integrable f such that:
$$F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) d x$$
Where $f(x)$ is the pdf.
But having only the CDF how do I know if such distribution have a pdf? 
I know that $F(x)$ is continuous, but is this sufficient to guarantee that $f(x)$ exists?
Should I take the first derivative of the CDF in each interval and then check whether the integral exists?

If f(x) exists, f(x) is :

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/4(x+2),  & \text{for $-2\le x<0$} \\
1/4, & \text{for $0\le x<2$ } \\
0,& \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Am I right? I am not sure whether I should include 2 in "for $0\le x<2 $". Should I?

Comment: " *I know that F(x) is continuous, but is this sufficient to guarantee that f(x) exists?* "  I would say, yes.

Comment: The question is slightly imprecise as it ask "Does $X$ has a density function$. By  Lebesgue decomposition Theorem, we can have discrete, continuous, and singular distribution, and of course the mixture of them. So if the question ask if it is a "pure" continuous distribution, you just check if it has any jump discontinuity (which is impossible if the CDF is continuous) and if it has any singular part (which is not as there is only countably many points may not be differentiable)

Comment: @BGM I think that we can refer to probability density functions f(x) iff we have an absolutely continuous F(x)

Comment: The vague part is that it can be a mixture of discrete and continuous distribution. So in such case, will you say it has a density function $f$?

Comment: I would say no. Anyways I am not sure

Comment: @Alchemy Your pdf looks good. Just use the same interval like at the cdf.